# How to treat a syntactical edit of an answer which turns something wrong into something correct?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In an case where some one gave a wrong answer as he for example mainly refers to a code snippet, which is even wrong coded. And some one edits the snippet to make it fit for answering the question correct, but it appears to be in conflict, or at least is not 100% sure that it will represent the intent of the original poster.

Is the edit aproveabal as it is an improvement for the informations contained on the site?

Or would it have to be rejected, as it is changing the core post (even if the core was wrong)?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I prefer reading a "different" but correct answer to my question than a wrong one.

Comment: If the edit changes the answer from flat-out-wrong to correct, it's probably a "radical change", and thus should be rejected. The proper course for the suggester would have been adding a comment, or his own answer.